# How to use pallet_timestamp on tests with function run_to_block?

Tags: configuration, unit-tests

I'm trying to use pallet_timestamp on function run_to_block when testing PalletA. Here is my code

```
pub fn run_to_block(n: u64) {
    while System::block_number() < n {
        if System::block_number() > 1 {
            PalletA::on_finalize(System::block_number());
            System::on_finalize(System::block_number());
        }
        System::set_block_number(System::block_number() + 1);
        System::on_initialize(System::block_number());
        PalletA::on_initialize(System::block_number());
        Timestamp::on_initialize(System::block_number());
       //Timestamp::on_finalize(System::block_number());  // Got error 'Timestamp must be updated once in the block'
    }
}
```

But on hooks of PalletA the '_now' value is always 0

```
    #[pallet::hooks]
    impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
        fn on_finalize(_block_number: BlockNumberFor<T>) {
            let _now = <timestamp::Pallet<T>>::get();

            println!("now: {:?}", _now);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Found solution dealing with pallet_timestamp on unittest:

```
pub fn run_to_block(n: u64) {
    while System::block_number() < n {
        if System::block_number() > 1 {
            PalletA::on_finalize(System::block_number());
            System::on_finalize(System::block_number());
        }
        System::set_block_number(System::block_number() + 1);
        System::on_initialize(System::block_number());
        PalletA::on_initialize(System::block_number());
        Timestamp::set_timestamp((System::block_number() as u64 * MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK) + INIT_TIMESTAMP); // New line
    }
}
```